Get strings before special character except apostrophe using stringr::word
Character string:
text="Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte/question et ne vous a pas orienté ailleurs"

I'd like to extract the part before "/". I tried
word(text,sep="[[:punct:]]")
[1] "Il n"

The problem in my situation is that I have many strings with different special characters at each one. Considering above example, the special character is "/" but it could be "," or ";" or "(" etc. So I am looking for a global solution.

You could replace apostrophe with a placeholder first, extract / split by [:punct:] and change placeholder back, something like text |> str_replace(fixed("’"), "|") |> str_split_i("[:punct:]", 1) |> str_replace(fixed("|"), "’")  . Must say it's actually somewhat surprising that [:punct:] does not match | here, but as long as it works ..

Your code is using any punctuation as a separator, and ’ qualifies as punctuation. If you want to restrict the category, either hard-code the list of alternatives as a character class (e.g. [/,;(]) or use a negative lookahead to match all punctuation except apostrophe etc.
Here’s the solution with the negative lookahead that excludes the apostrophe. You can add other characters as required; however, note that there’s no way to distinguish between apostrophe and the (English) single closing quotation mark — at least not on the character level.
word(text, sep = '(?!’)[[:punct:]]')
# [1] "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte"


You can specify multiple separators as vector, as regex list, or by combining them with |.
texts=c("Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte/question et ne vous a pas orienté ailleurs",
        "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte; question et ne vous a pas orienté ailleurs",
        "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte (question et ne vous a pas orienté ailleurs)")

word(texts,sep=c("/",";","\\("))
# [1] "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte"  "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte" 
# [3] "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte "

word(texts,sep="[/;\\(]")
# [1] "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte"  "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte" 
# [3] "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte "

word(texts,sep="/|;|\\(")
# [1] "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte"  "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte" 
# [3] "Il n’a pas réussi à répondre à votre plainte "

Note that separators that are special regex characters (e.g., !, (, {, ...) must be escaped with \\.

You don’t need to separate special characters inside [] character classes (except the closing ], or - if it occurs between two characters).

@KonradRudolph Yes and I didn't, see my example. I suggest providing a regex list or several characters separated by | as different options.

Interestingly it seems acceptable not to escape some special characters in brackets (as word(texts,sep="[(.]") gives the expected output), if that's what you meant.

Ah yes, I meant escape, not “separate”. — Most characters are not special characters inside character classes so don’t need to be escaped.
